# Crystal Report with 3rd level sub report ( for one record, i need two detail sections)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a main report in which there are multiple articles, and each article has material (items).
On the first level, I have grouped articles by article and then shown each article's material in the group detail section.

But the problem is that each article has technical specifications as well. (multiple properties, like material or items). how i will manage technical specification[image]on part?

I have used a sub-report for technical specifications, but it repeats all technical specifications of all articles with each article group.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal can't have a subreport inside a subreport.But you can work around that limitation in several ways.

One option is to make the 2nd level (Materials) the main report, Grouped by the 1st level (Items). You can then insert the 1st level as a subreport in the Group header, and the 3rd-level (Specifications) as a subreport in the Group footer.

Another option, assuming you will deliver the output as a PDF file, is to use a Crystal Reports Automation tool to insert the related specifications as embedded documents linked to a drill-down icon for each material section. The user would then be able to click on an icon to drill-down into the Specifications. One of the report automation tools listed by Ken Hamady [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) provides that functionality.